# Arrangement of columns data in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

[This is my sheet in which i have written how i want my data pls visit and help me out](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u1aqYcRLnsMGvK5sktsw9qfX3vsdRDtu0y9Pz3ksMT4/edit?usp=sharing)
I have created above sheet so that i can explain how i want my data i hv explained my query here i am giving you a brief, is that i want to see that the person who is filling the form shoul upload all the images all the column headers are basically one question so that user can upload images of that location and they can upload one picture one at a time or all questions in one go but problem is if the person to forget to upload any one of the questions then i should tell him that you hv not uploaded image of that region so pls help me out with this pls visit this sheet so that you can complete clearity of this questions.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>""))&"♦"&C1:L1)), 
 SORT(SPLIT(FLATTEN(B2:B23&"♦"&C1:L1&"×"&B2:B23&"×"&C1:L1&"×"&C2:L23), "×"), 4, 1), {2, 3, 4}, 0)))
```

[image]

### [demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qz6vhm9Kv51KUf-7HtUwwsg9XVDoFW03OVbCYn9tab4/edit#gid=0)